# Ubuntu 22.04 mouse and keyboard are hanging

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, 22.04, mouse

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and after that the mouse and keyboard are hanging a lot, I tried restarting the laptop but when I open it the same problems appear every about 20 minutes,
my laptop is Dell G5 5520
Ram 16 GB
processor intel core i7 12th generation
Nividia RTX 3050 4GB

[image]

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version. There is no Ubuntu 22 desktop release. Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: ubuntu 22.04
yes installed

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Terminal output is text.

Comment: I added the output of this command

Comment: Sorry I am trying to do this but unfortunately the mouse and keyboard are hanging and I can't copy it from the terminal

Comment: No problem. Install the drivers and reboot.

Comment: How can I install them? From nvidia website or something else

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: When I came to install the drivers through the gui I got multiple choices how can I select between them

Comment: Select the 525 driver. The top one, that says tested.

Comment: This didn't work, it gave me a x in a circle and ok

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: I installed it. Is there anything to do

Comment: Do you still have a problem?

Comment: It didn't happen until now

Comment: So the problem is solved. You can accept the answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am still facing the same issue, updating the drivers minimized the problem but it is not fully solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Install Nvidia drivers using Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers application.

You can also do it by a terminal command

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Then reboot.